# How to convert an `IO ()` to `JSVal` in GHCJS

Tags: haskell, ffi, ghcjs

i want to execute some effectful computation on a regular basis in a program compiled with GHCJS, but `GHCJS.DOM.WindowTimers.setInterval` wants a `JSVal` as parameter. Could anybody give me some pointers for turning my `IO ()` into a `JSVal`?

#### Edit:

I was able to match the types using `GHCJS.Foreign.Callback.asyncCallback` and `GHCJS.Types.jsval`, but i have eventually got a runtime error. Luite in the GHCJS channel suggested to use threads for this task, as Erik suggested in a comment here. This is explained in [the corresponding question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33611149/how-to-execute-an-action-periodically-in-a-ghcjs-program)

Comment: you _could_ just use threads and have GHCJS take care of the plumbing.

Comment: this is an answer to a slightly different question, that i created for you here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33611149/how-to-execute-an-action-periodically-in-a-ghcjs-program :)