# How to execute an action periodically in a GHCJS program?

Tags: haskell, concurrency, ghcjs

Should one use `setInterval` via Javascript, or use some more idiomatic solution based on threads?

Comment: If you only target the browser then I think it's just a matter of taste. A solution using `threadDelay` *will* work when compiled with GHCJS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**If you don't care about the motivation, just scroll to my best solution `runPeriodicallyConstantDrift` below.** If you prefer a simpler solution with worse results, then see `runPeriodicallySmallDrift`.

My answer is not GHCJS specific, and has not been tested on GHCJS, only GHC, but it illustrates problems with [the OP's naive solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33614603/470844).

#### First Strawman Solution: `runPeriodicallyBigDrift`

Here's my version of the OP's solution, for comparison below:

```hs
import           Control.Concurrent ( threadDelay )
import           Control.Monad ( forever )

-- | Run @action@ every @period@ seconds.
runPeriodicallyBigDrift :: Double -> IO () -> IO ()
runPeriodicallyBigDrift period action = forever $ do
  action
  threadDelay (round $ period * 10 ** 6)
```

Assuming "execute an action periodically" means the action *starts* every period many seconds, **the OP's solution is problematic because the `threadDelay` doesn't take into account the time the action itself takes. After n iterations, the start time of the action will have drifted by at least the time it takes to run the action n times!**

#### Second Strawman Solution: `runPeriodicallySmallDrift`

So, we if we actually want to start a new action every period, we need to take into account the time it takes the action to run. If the period is relatively large compared to the time it takes to spawn a thread, then this simple solution may work for you:

```
import           Control.Concurrent ( threadDelay )
import           Control.Concurrent.Async ( async, link )
import           Control.Monad ( forever )

-- | Run @action@ every @period@ seconds.
runPeriodicallySmallDrift :: Double -> IO () -> IO ()
runPeriodicallySmallDrift period action = forever $ do
  -- We reraise any errors raised by the action, but
  -- we don't check that the action actually finished within one
  -- period. If the action takes longer than one period, then
  -- multiple actions will run concurrently.
  link =<< async action
  threadDelay (round $ period * 10 ** 6)
```

In my experiments (more details below), it takes about 0.001 seconds to spawn a thread on my system, so the drift for `runPeriodicallySmallDrift` after n iterations is about n thousandths of a second, which may be negligible in some use cases.

#### Final Solution: `runPeriodicallyConstantDrift`

Finally, suppose we require only constant drift, meaning the drift is always less than some constant, and does not grow with the number of iterations of the periodic action. We can achieve constant drift by keeping track of the total time since we started, and starting the `n`th iteration when the total time is `n` times the period:

```
import           Control.Concurrent ( threadDelay )
import           Data.Time.Clock.POSIX ( getPOSIXTime )
import           Text.Printf ( printf )

-- | Run @action@ every @period@ seconds.
runPeriodicallyConstantDrift :: Double -> IO () -> IO ()
runPeriodicallyConstantDrift period action = do
  start <- getPOSIXTime
  go start 1
  where
    go start iteration = do
      action
      now <- getPOSIXTime
      -- Current time.
      let elapsed = realToFrac $ now - start
      -- Time at which to run action again.
      let target = iteration * period
      -- How long until target time.
      let delay = target - elapsed
      -- Fail loudly if the action takes longer than one period.  For
      -- some use cases it may be OK for the action to take longer
      -- than one period, in which case remove this check.
      when (delay < 0 ) $ do
        let msg = printf "runPeriodically: action took longer than one period: delay = %f, target = %f, elapsed = %f"
                  delay target elapsed
        error msg
      threadDelay (round $ delay * microsecondsInSecond)
      go start (iteration + 1)
    microsecondsInSecond = 10 ** 6
```

Based on experiments below, the drift is always about 1/1000th of a second, independent of the number of iterations of the action.

#### Comparison Of Solutions By Testing

To compare these solutions, we create an action that keeps track of its own drift and tells us, and run it in each of the `runPeriodically*` implementations above:

```
import           Control.Concurrent ( threadDelay )
import           Data.IORef ( newIORef, readIORef, writeIORef )
import           Data.Time.Clock.POSIX ( getPOSIXTime )
import           Text.Printf ( printf )

-- | Use a @runPeriodically@ implementation to run an action
-- periodically with period @period@. The action takes
-- (approximately) @runtime@ seconds to run.
testRunPeriodically :: (Double -> IO () -> IO ()) -> Double -> Double -> IO ()
testRunPeriodically runPeriodically runtime period = do
  iterationRef <- newIORef 0
  start <- getPOSIXTime
  startRef <- newIORef start
  runPeriodically period $ action startRef iterationRef
  where
    action startRef iterationRef = do
      now <- getPOSIXTime
      start <- readIORef startRef
      iteration <- readIORef iterationRef
      writeIORef iterationRef (iteration + 1)
      let drift = (iteration * period) - (realToFrac $ now - start)
      printf "test: iteration = %.0f, drift = %f\n" iteration drift
      threadDelay (round $ runtime * 10**6)
```

Here are the test results. In each case test an action that runs for 0.05 seconds, and use a period of twice that, i.e. 0.1 seconds.

For `runPeriodicallyBigDrift`, the drift after n iterations is about n times the runtime of a single iteration, as expected. After 100 iterations the drift is -5.15, and the predicted drift just from runtime of the action is -5.00:

```
ghci> testRunPeriodically runPeriodicallyBigDrift 0.05 0.1
...
test: iteration = 98, drift = -5.045410253
test: iteration = 99, drift = -5.096661091
test: iteration = 100, drift = -5.148137684
test: iteration = 101, drift = -5.199764033999999
test: iteration = 102, drift = -5.250980596
...
```

For `runPeriodicallySmallDrift`, the drift after n iterations is about 0.001 seconds, presumably the time it takes to spawn a thread on my system:

```
ghci> testRunPeriodically runPeriodicallySmallDrift 0.05 0.1
...
test: iteration = 98, drift = -0.08820333399999924
test: iteration = 99, drift = -0.08908210599999933
test: iteration = 100, drift = -0.09006684400000076
test: iteration = 101, drift = -0.09110764399999915
test: iteration = 102, drift = -0.09227584299999947
...
```

For `runPeriodicallyConstantDrift`, the drift remains constant (plus noise) at about 0.001 seconds:

```
ghci> testRunPeriodically runPeriodicallyConstantDrift 0.05 0.1
...
test: iteration = 98, drift = -0.0009586619999986112
test: iteration = 99, drift = -0.0011010979999994674
test: iteration = 100, drift = -0.0011610369999992542
test: iteration = 101, drift = -0.0004908619999977049
test: iteration = 102, drift = -0.0009897379999994627
...
```

If we cared about that level of constant drift, then a more sophisticiated solution could track the average constant drift and adjust for it.

#### Generalization To Stateful Periodic Loops

In practice I realized that some of my loops have state that passes from one iteration to the next. Here's a slight generalization of `runPeriodicallyConstantDrift` to support that:

```
import           Control.Concurrent ( threadDelay )
import           Data.IORef ( newIORef, readIORef, writeIORef )
import           Data.Time.Clock.POSIX ( getPOSIXTime )
import           Text.Printf ( printf )

-- | Run a stateful @action@ every @period@ seconds.
--
-- Achieves uniformly bounded drift (i.e. independent of the number of
-- iterations of the action) of about 0.001 seconds,
runPeriodicallyWithState :: Double -> st -> (st -> IO st) -> IO ()
runPeriodicallyWithState period st0 action = do
  start <- getPOSIXTime
  go start 1 st0
  where
    go start iteration st = do
      st' <- action st
      now <- getPOSIXTime
      let elapsed = realToFrac $ now - start
      let target = iteration * period
      let delay = target - elapsed
      -- Warn if the action takes longer than one period. Originally I
      -- was failing in this case, but in my use case we sometimes,
      -- but very infrequently, take longer than the period, and I
      -- don't actually want to crash in that case.
      when (delay < 0 ) $ do
        printf "WARNING: runPeriodically: action took longer than one period: delay = %f, target = %f, elapsed = %f"
          delay target elapsed
      threadDelay (round $ delay * microsecondsInSecond)
      go start (iteration + 1) st'
    microsecondsInSecond = 10 ** 6

-- | Run a stateless @action@ every @period@ seconds.
--
-- Achieves uniformly bounded drift (i.e. independent of the number of
-- iterations of the action) of about 0.001 seconds,
runPeriodically :: Double -> IO () -> IO ()
runPeriodically period action =
  runPeriodicallyWithState period () (const action)
```

Comment: aheam given the amount of research and experiments you put in, i marked your answer as the best solution ... but to be honest i don't have the time going through all the motivations and the whole thread. I reckon that just setting a thread delay is not precise ... there has to be a simpler way to launch a thread at a given interval, even thought this might cause more of such threads to be running at the same time. Otherwise i think that i prefer the solution where the execution of the next thread is delayed a bit

Comment: also, it would be way more readable if you proposed your solution at the beginning of your text, adding the motivations & research after for who's interested ... but as far as i see your final solution involves a lot of complexity, many readers will still be more likely to prefer the one that drifts in time

Comment: @danza regarding the final solution being complex, did you look at the `runPeriodicallySmallDrift` version? That version is very simple, but also keeps the drift relatively small.

Comment: @danza I put the note about jumping to the final solution if you don't care about the motivations first, and added more comments and prose to the final solution. See if it makes sense now.

Comment: @danza, I am confident that it took much longer to research and construct this answer than it would take for you to read it carefully. The comments you make above are the sort that will make people think twice about taking the time to answer your questions.

Comment: @dfeuer i accept your criticism. not everyone has equal time availability in different moments. i am not interested in this answer at the moment. i am discussing with ntc2 in order to give more visibility to their research, which is here not only for me but for anyone interested in performing this rather common action using this technology. this is also the reason why i wrote the question, by the way, not just for myself

Comment: @ntc2 i believe that the second strawman solution you propose will fit most use cases, and many programmers will easily adapt the code in order to support concurrent executions cleanly. that is what i had in mind, it's very essential and simple. all at all an excellent answer, thanks!

Comment: i'm considering whether to edit the question in order to generalise it to haskell ... but in that case probably we could move your answer to some official haskell documentation page? on a side note, i would present the second solution as "concurrent actions" or "overlapping executions", it can be fine for some uses

Answer (score 8):

Using `setInterval` posed [some challenges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33576618/how-to-convert-an-io-to-jsval-in-ghcjs) and comments from Alexander, Erik and Luite himself led me to try threads. This worked seamlessly, with very clean code similar to the following:

```
import Control.Concurrent( forkIO, threadDelay )
import Control.Monad( forever )

... within an IO block
threadId <- forkIO $ forever $ do
  threadDelay (60 * 1000 * 1000) -- one minute in microseconds, not milliseconds like in Javascript!
  doWhateverYouLikeHere
```

Haskell has the concept of lightweight threads so this is the idiomatic Haskell way to run an action in an asynchronous way as you would do with a Javascript `setInterval` or `setTimeout`.

- [Hackage](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Control-Concurrent.html)
- [Real world Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/concurrent-and-multicore-programming.html)